# Is it possible to change the content of a custom taxonomy admin interface

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to change the content of the admin interface of a custom taxonomy i've created for woocommerce products.

TL:DR -
I've got a custom taxonomy, that i want to display a custom template file for. It currently loads in "Category", but that's not what i need on that page.

---

I'm currently registering my taxonomy as is:

```
public function add_user_specific_pricing_taxonomy() {
        $args = array( 
            'labels'                     => array(
                'name'                      => esc_html__( 'User Specific Pricing', 'Taxonomy General Name', $this->plugin_name ),
                'singular_name'             => esc_html__( 'User Specific Price', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', $this->plugin_name ),
                'menu_name'                 => esc_html__( 'User Specific Pricing', $this->plugin_name ),
            ),
            'hierarchical'               => true,
            'has_archive'                => true,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'show_tagcloud'              => true,
            'show_in_rest'               => true,
        );
        register_taxonomy("product_user_specific_pricing", 'product', $args );
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'product_user_specific_pricing', 'product' );
    }
```

`add_action( 'init', 'add_user_specific_pricing_taxonomy', 0 );`

I've then tried adding a template file in my theme, named it: *taxonomy-product_user_specific_pricing.php*

This didn't help any. I've then tried add it from my plugin itself, where i register this custom taxonomy by filtering it:

```
public function custom_taxonomy_template( $template ) {
        if (is_tax('product_user_specific_pricing')) {
            $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/taxonomy-product_user_specific_pricing.php';
            return $template;
        }
    }

add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_taxonomy_template', 0 );
```

But that didn't seem to help at all either. I'm currently stuck here.

Any help is much appreciate!